# can't make a dump of the mnesia database

Tags: erlang, mnesia

How can i make a dump of a mnesia database or table. I get an error if i exacte the example below (i do have full control over the folder 777)

```
./ejabberdctl backup /var/log/tmp/dump.txt
Can't store backup in "/var/www/log/tmp/dump.txt" at node ejabberd@localhost: {'EXIT',
{error,
{file_error,
"/var/www/log/tmp/dump.txt.BUPTMP",
eacces}}}

./ejabberdctl dump_table /var/www/log/test.txt vcard
Can't store dump in "/var/www/fastguide/tmp/test.txt" at node ejabberd@localhost: eacces
```

What am i doing wrong?

And is there a way to look in the database?

Answer (score 1):

[`eaccess`](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) is the error code for `Permission denied`. The user running the command probably doesn't have write permissions for the directories where you tried to store the dump file. The easiest way to check this is by running `touch /var/www/log/foo.txt`, if it fails then you need another user than can write to this directory.